# How to get sub String from String in Php

Tags: php

I have a string like

```
$totalValues ="4565:4,4566:5,4567:6";
```

Now i want only values after `':'` with coma separated ,i.e i want string like `$SubValues = "4,5,6"`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$totalValues ="4565:4,4566:5,4567:6";

echo implode(',',array_map(function($val){
    $val = explode(':',$val);
    return $val[1];
},explode(',',$totalValues)));
```

Comment: Thanks @roullie, you saved my time , could you explain your code briefly.

Comment: can i get string like "4565,4566,4567" ?

Comment: of course.  change `return $val[1];` to `return $val[0];`

Answer (score 2):

> **try this code it is working**

```
   <?php
    $str="4565:4,4566:5,4567:6";;
    $data =explode(",", $str);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    $newstring="";
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        preg_match('/:(.*)/',$value,$matches);
        $newstring.=$matches[1].",";

    }
    echo rtrim($newstring,",");
```

Output
[image: o/p image]

i have updated my code please check it

```
<?php
    $str="4565:4,4566:5,4567:6";
    $data1=explode(",", $str);
    $newstring1="";
    foreach ($data1 as $key1 => $value) {
        preg_match('/(.*?):/',$value,$matches);
        $newstring1.=$matches[1].",";

    }
    echo rtrim($newstring1,",");
```

[image: O/P]

Comment: Thank you @Sharma Vikram , now i want  "4565,4566,4567"  string also , please help me

Answer (score 0):

you might want it this way:

```
$totalValues ="4565:4,4566:5,4567:6";
$temp = explode(':', $totalValues); 
$subValues = $temp[1][0];
$x = count($temp);
for ($i = 2; $i < $x; $i++) {
    $subValues .= ',' . $temp[$i][0];
}
echo $subValues;
```